# Trajectory of a projectile.

Tags: calculus, conic-sections

From the definition of a parabola can we prove that the trajectory of a projectile is parabolic? And can this be proved by calculus?

Comment: If you don't take into account the air resistance, and assume the object is attracted to the centre of the earth inversely proportional to the distance from the center itself, you get an ellipse.

Comment: I am taking g as an constant.

Comment: http://www.pha.jhu.edu/~broholm/l5/node3.html and also: http://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0310049.pdf

Comment: Derivation of trajectory of projectile https://www.physicskey.com/11/derivation-of-trajectory-of-projectile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this can be proved using calculus but this a simple proof using equations of motion.

Let us assume that a projectile is being fired from the origin.

angle of projection = some $\theta$.

velocity of projection = $v$

therefore

-the upward component of velocity = $v\sin(\theta)$

using the equation $s=ut+\frac{at^2}2$, for the upward motion, we get

$$y=v\sin(\theta)t-\frac{gt^2}2\tag{1}$$

and as there is no acceleration in the horizontal direction $x=v(cos(\theta))t$.

threfore $t=\frac{x}{v\cos(\theta)}$. substituting the value of $t$ in equation $(1)$ we get $$y= x\tan(\theta)-\dfrac {gx^2}{2v^2\cos^2\theta},$$ which exactly resembles the equation of a parabola due to the presence of a squared term :

$y=ax-bx^2$. hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Let a projectile is thrown with velocity 'u' at an angle 'theta' with horizontal and after 't' time , it reaches at  one point. 
  Then, Using the equation:

$$ S=Ut+(1/2)at^2   ~~~~~~~[1]$$

But, Projectile is thrown upward (against acceleration) 
So,

$$S=Ut-(1/2)gt^2  ~~~~~~~[2]$$

Now,

Using $S_y=Uy-(1/2)gt^2$
we get,

$ y=Usin \theta t -(1/2)gt^2$

or,$ y= Usin \theta×(x/Ucos \theta) - (1/2)(x^2/U^2cos^2 \theta)$

[Since,$ t=x/(Ucos \theta)$]
Thus,

$$y=tan \theta - ({g x^2 \over 2U^2cos^2 \theta})  ~~~~[3]$$

Hence,
Equation [3] shows 
               $y=ax-bx^2$
Therefore this proves that trajectory of projectile is parabolic.